# Unable to use ssjs-rows-retrieve in a API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I need to post the data extension values to an external system, I planned to use a script activity containing `Rows.Retrieve` which will give me JSON object and the post it in doPost of REST method.

But this is failing. Does anyone have any solution for this?

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var url = 'endpoint URL';

var stagingDE = DataExtension.Init('DE'S External Key');
var data = stagingDE.Rows.Retrieve();
var newString = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
var str1 = "'";
var str2 = str1.concat(newString);
var str3 = "'";
var str4= str2.concat(str3);

var payload =str4;

var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
req.retries = 2;
req.continueOnError = true;
req.contentType = "application/json";
req.method = "POST"; 
req.postData = payload;
var resp = req.send();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "But this is failing."?

Comment: Hi @lukas Lunow, I am unable to get the exact error. Because the email result when the process is failed says STATUS Error.

Comment: Is there any way to get the exact error. I am a newbie here

Comment: Is it a generic error 500?

Comment: if I give exact string json formatted value for the var payload, it works! All i need to get the DE values in this format now

Comment: yes a generic error @Lukas Lunow

Comment: Using HttpRequest at sendtime is really bad practice. For testing SSJS I will recommend you to use CloudPages, where you can debug the code easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104651/discussion-between-clouddot-and-lukas-lunow).